# C# How to check for administrator rights / privileges

Tags: c#

I want to create a folder with my C# app. I'm writing code, for me all is ok, but my friend gets an error

> Access to the path 'myfolder' is denied.

So how can I ask for admin rights? I've searched that it can be created with manifest..  What's it? How/where can I get manifest? I'm newbie sorry. I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Say to your friend to run your application "As Administrator", right click-> "Run as Administrator"

Comment: @Tinwor it's not an original answer to my problem, i need to fix it with code..

Comment: basically if you haven't administration right you can't access to that particular folder. My suggestion is a workaround and should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Suggestion 1 to check admin rights - this one is if you want to do something with the bool value within the code after you do your checks

This will return a bool value and allow you to do what you want with the`isAdmin`

```
using System.Security.Principal;

bool isAdmin;
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

> Suggest 2 - force my .NET App to run as administrator - this is the one i would do if you always want it to run as administrator and is the one i would suggest to use.

You'll want to modify the manifest that gets embedded in the program. This works on VS2008 and higher: Project + Add New Item, select "Application Manifest File". Change the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` element to:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

The user gets the UAC prompt when they start the program.

Comment: Where can i find manifest? And how to create it? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for desktop